# How to get the root document which a subcollection document belongs to?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

After getting a snapshot for a particular document in a subcollection, I would like to get the associated data to the root document which it belongs to.

For example, there is a collection *restaurants* and each one has a *products* subcollection.
After searching for a particular product of a restaurant, how can I get the restaurant data which the product belongs to? Do I need to make another search or how can I get it from the product snapshot?

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('products').get();

QueryDocumentSnapshot product = snapshot.docs.elementAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a very easy way to do this, and it takes advantage of the ref.path of the document.  You can split the ref.path string into it's component sections - remember, it's the full "/" separated path to the document, so for example:

```
restaurants/{restaurantId}/products/{productId}
topCollection/{topdocumentId}/nextCollection/{nextDocumentId}/.../bottomCollection/{bottomDocumentId}
```

Clearly, the *first two* segments are the path to the "parent" document - *regardless* of the depth of the tree (I happen to have a very deep tree structure).  You can then fetch the "top parent":

```
db.collection(topCollection).doc(topdocumentId).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the parent/restaurant document for `product`, you'll want to walk up the reference/parent chain:

```
var restaurantRef = product.reference.parent.parent;
```

You will still need to `get` that document with:

```
var restaurantDoc = await restaurantRef.get();
```